# Generate table using raw SQL query and want to use those tables as ORM in Django

Tags: sql, django, orm

```
table_title = 'transaction_' + username
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + table_title + '(id uuid NOT NULL,
    sql += 'amount numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
    sql += 'CONSTRAINT transaction_pkey' + username + ' PRIMARY KEY (id),'
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

I have create table using this code.
Now what I want:

- I want to use them in the application's **admin.py**
- I want show them in **Django**'s admin panel
- I want to use this table as **ORM** in views.

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Why not using django models? You can create a model in models.py, and you can use the built-in admin site and ORM. What is the advantage of using raw SQL here?

Comment: I have to create table space separate for each user.

Example: If I signup using username 'rkshaon', then there will be generate a different transaction table for user 'rkshaon'. 

I have to do this.

Comment: Why would you need that? What's the reason that you want separate table for each user?

Comment: Because I am working on a project, where there will be huge data for each user. So I had asked to separate tables for each user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those huge data for each user won't be in a single table because each type of data will be in different tables. Maybe first you should just design a proper database structure for each type of data, and then see if there's a problem there. What you're trying to do doesn't sound logical.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way use ORM while you execute raw SQL. If you want to an admin panel you have to develop your own custom admin panel.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This would be better as a comment rather than an answer.  Check out [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)